# Replication of a docker-compose service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-swarm, orchestration

I have client-server application in a docker-compose file that is running in docker-swarm. 
Both the client and the server are publishing a port, that allows accessing the application in the browser.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    client:
        image: phalanx8/user_enum_openssh-client
        ports:
            - "0.0.0.0:8888:8080"
        networks:
            - main_network
    server:
        image: phalanx8/user_enum_openssh-server
        ports:
            - "0.0.0.0:8081:8080"
        networks:
            - main_network

networks:
  main_network:
```

My goes is that every time a request was made, a client-server application should be replicated. So every user is getting their own environment.

Replicating each service (client/server) with `docker service service_name_(client/server)=X` doesn't work because the network isn't replicated too.

My idea was to copy the `docker-compose.yml` at every request, which I think isn't a smooth solution.

Is there a better way? Am I missing something in the docker-swarm configuration? Does Kubernetes provide a solution for this? I cant find anything.

Comment: How would you direct the new connections to the new environment that has been created?

Comment: Kubernetes at least provides a well defined API, so a parent process watching for incoming connections could spawn to new environment and direct users to it when running. You would probably need to write that software though.